# Yup validator - Phone number not required but with min value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, validation, yup

I have this structure on my react app:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
 phone: yup.string().min(13, "Invalid number")

});
```

But I want to make possible for the phone to be either 13 characters length or empty, how can I do that?

I've tried using .nullable() and .nullable("") but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
 phone: yup.string()
   .matches(/.{13,}/, {
    excludeEmptyString: true,
    message: 'Must be 13 characters',
  });
});
```